# What is this "anonymous moderator comment"?

Tags: support, post-notice

On this [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/38520/22581), there is the following comment:

[image]

But there is no username associated with it, nor is there any option to vote on or flag it. I've been a member on Stack Exchange for a while, but I've never seen anything like this before. My guess is that this is some type of moderator comment. I'd like to know what this is and, if possible, some information about where this feature came from (i.e. a Meta post or Blog post describing the need for it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is known as a post notice, and I was the one who posted this one.

While I could've easily posted a comment to that user, I've decided to use a post notice to make the message more visible for others.  I do not know if that particular answer was migrated from SO, though.  If it was, that would be understandable.  *But* it seemed out of place on CR as we generally discourage such answers with little to no explanation.  I certainly didn't want to delete it outright since it has some merit as an answer, although it may still be prone to downvotes and/or deletion by the community.

You're right; it cannot be voted on directly.  But you can still flag that post and provide a custom message for adding/removing a post notice.  In most cases, another user would flag to remove a post notice if that post has been improved by someone.

More info can be found on [this MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post).